# How does the ground state of the quantum Ising model relate to Schrodinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, ising-model

The Hamiltonian
$$H = -\sum_{i\in V} h_i \sigma_i^z -\sum_{(i,j)\in E} J_{ij} \sigma_i^z\sigma_j^z - \Gamma\sum_{i\in V} \sigma_i^x$$
is kind of the cost function of the quantum annealing optimization problem. The ground state is kind of the optimal solution. The ground state is the eigenvector of $H$ corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue. However, if I put this $H$ into the Schrodinger equation $$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\lvert\psi\rangle = H\lvert\psi\rangle$$ and  solve it, the solution $\lvert\psi\rangle$ is an oscillating vector nothing related to the ground state vector. My question is, is the Hamiltonian in the quantum Ising model and the Hamiltonian in the Schrodinger equation the same concept? How does the ground state vector in quantum Ising model relate to the state vector in the Schrodinger equation?

Comment: Essentially, you are asking the difference between Time Independent Schrodinger Equation (TISE) and Time Dependent Schrodinger Equation (TDSE), am I right?

Comment: No. Essentially, I'm asking how to arrive the ground state from an initial state according to Schrodinger equation. Given an initial state and the Hamiltonian, the solution to the Schrodinger equation is kind of oscillating sinusoidal. It will never go to a steady state of the ground state.

Answer (score 1):

> is the Hamiltonian in the quantum Ising model and the Hamiltonian in the Schrodinger equation the same concept?

Yes, the two Hamiltonians are the same. The Hamiltonian is part of the definition of the model (in this case, the Ising model). Once the Hamiltonian has been specified, the Schrödinger equation tells us how any given state-vector evolves in time.

> How does the ground state vector in quantum Ising model relate to the state vector in the Schrodinger equation?

The Schrödinger equation tells us how a *given* state evolves in time. If we use the ground state in the Schrödinger equation, then the Schrödinger equation just tells us that the state doesn't change in time (except for a physically irrelevant overall complex factor), which is true for *any* eigenstate of $H$.

The ground state is defined to be the eigenstate of $H$ with the lowest eigenvalue. This definition is logically unrelated to the Schrödinger equation. The Schrödinger equation applies to *any* state, whether or not it happens to be the ground state.

Comment: In the processing of quantum annealing, the ground state is the final state that the system will arrive, starting from an initial state. And the state evolution is described by Schrodinger equation. So the ground state should be the steady-state of the solution of the Schrodinger equation. But this is not true. Given an initial state, according to the Schrodinger equation, the state will never converge to the ground state. There must be something wrong in my interpretation. Can you point out what's wrong?

Comment: @JunkWarrior  I'm not an expert in quantum annealing, but here is one way to address it, at least in principle. (Maybe too hard in practice.) In principle, we can extend the model to include an "environment" that  absorbs the excess energy as the system-of-interest cools toward _its_ ground state. In this case, "ground state" refers to what _would_ be the ground state if the environment were ignored. Since the extended Hamiltonian also includes terms that couple the system-of-interest to the environment, the total system can converge to this "ground state".

Comment: @JunkWarrior  A simpler analogy is one that uses an isolated atom in place of the spin-system.  In an atom-only QM model that doesn't include the EM field, an excited atom never decays, because it's an eigenstate of the atom-only Hamiltonian. But that model isn't realistic. To make it more realistic, we can include the EM field, and then the excess energy has somewhere to go; an excited atom is no longer an eigenstate of this extended Hamiltonian. The final state won't be the gound state of the _whole system_ (because of the outgoing photons), but the _atom_ will end up in _its_ ground state.